# What does "(<$>)" do in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

in the functional programming language Haskell, what does "(<$>)" do? I cannot find any documentation on it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-

Comment: @alias That's the documentation, but have you read it? It's completely incomprehensible if you don't already know what `<$>` or `fmap` do.

Comment: @amalloy There's a few simple examples right in the documentation, starting with `show <$> Nothing` which should help illustrate. Perhaps the link is more to addressing the concern that the OP couldn't find any documentation on it, thus directing them to the hackage site.

Comment: @amalloy The OP said "I cannot find any documentation on it", not "I found the documentation for it but I can't understand it".

Comment: @amalloy So step 2 is to learn what `fmap` does. Stack Overflow doesn't need to be alternate documentation for every single basic question one can imagine about a language.

Comment: https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(%24)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's an infix operator version of `fmap`. I like to think of it as something that can can *bring* (most say *lift*) a pure function into some context, as long as this context is a functor (and most data-types having a type-parameter can be turned into functors).

For example, let's say you have a function

```hs
double :: Int -> Int
double x = 2 * x
```

but you are dealing with `Maybe` values in  a list `[Nothing, Just 3, Just 1, Nothing, Just 0]`. You'd like to double every `Just`-number but you don't know how.

You know there is `map` for the list but how do deal with the `Maybe`s?

you could write

```hs
doubleList :: [Maybe Int] -> [Maybe Int]
doubleList = map doubleMaybe
   where doubleMaybe (Just n) = Just (2*n)
         doubleMaybe Nothing = Nothing
```

but that seems silly as you already have `double`

Here comes `fmap` into play - `fmap` *lifts* `double` into `Maybe`: `fmap double :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int`:

```hs
doubleList :: [Maybe Int] -> [Maybe Int]
doubleList = map (fmap double)
```

or as a list is a functor too

```hs
doubleList :: [Maybe Int] -> [Maybe Int]
doubleList = fmap (fmap double)
```

or

```hs
doubleList :: [Maybe Int] -> [Maybe Int]
doubleList = (fmap . fmap) double
```

`<$>` comes handy if you have *points* - so `fmap double (Just 5) = double <$> Just 5`.

You see this often with `IO` computations (lift some function into `IO`) and often with *applicatives*.

For this let's look at

```hs
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add = (+)
```

how to add two numbers that are wrapped in `Maybe`?

Here `<$>` and `<*>` are really handy:

```hs
> add <$> Just 4 <*> Just 5
Just 9

> add <$> Just 4 <*> Nothing
Nothing

> add <$> Nothing <*> Just 5
Nothing

> add <$> Nothing <*> Nothing
Nothing
```

IMO applicatives are not that important to learn right away. Usually you can write those using `do` notation instead and from what I've seen beginners - especially coming from more imperative languages - have no trouble with that:

```hs
... do
   a <- Just 4
   b <- Just 5
   pure $ add a b
```

but *Functors* are really everywhere - I guess it's a matter of getting used to it.

If you see a `SomeType a` and you want a `SomeType b` and you know how to `a -> b` or if you want a `SomeType a -> SomeType b` and know/have `a -> b` - *Functor*, `fmap` and `<$>` should come to your mind immediately.